# how to write a test for the linked model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help to write the test for the model.

a model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :guestbooks
  has_secure_password
end
```

a model Guestbook:

```
class Guestbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

table users:

```
id: integer
name: varchar
email: varchar
diary_name: varchar
```

table guestbooks:

```
id: integer
message: text
user_id: integer
```

I am trying to write a test:

```
class GuestbookTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.create(
                          name: 'namee', 
                          email: 'adddd@ad.ad', 
                          diary_name: 'dnndndnррррnd', 
                          password: 'qwerty', 
                          password_confirmation: 'qwerty'
                        )
  end

  test "should save guestbook for signin user" do
    guestbook = Guestbook.new(message: 'dfsdfsf gdfgfdghfghfghf ghfgh ', user_id: @user)
    assert guestbook.save
  end  
end
```

as a result of getting the following error message:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/ZSUM $ rake test:models
Run options: --seed 19425
# Running:
F
Finished in 0.349347s, 2.8625 runs/s, 2.8625 assertions/s.
  1) Failure:
GuestbookTest#test_should_save_guestbook_for_signin_user [/home/kalinin/rails/ZSUM/test/models/guestbook_test.rb:18]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Where did those other columns on `User` come from (password and password_confirmation)?  Do you have `attr_accessible` for `password` and `password_confirmation`?

Comment: has_secure_password creates them

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
  test "should save guestbook for signin user" do
    guestbook = Guestbook.new(message: 'dfsdfsf gdfgfdghfghfghf ghfgh ', user_id: @user)
    assert guestbook.save!
  end
```

and in model remakr name validation:

```
class Guestbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validates :name,      presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :message,   presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000, minimum: 10 }

  belongs_to :user
end
```